# SMT2 format logfile

Tags: z3

I am trying to change to output format of the logfile of Z3 to SMT2 format using the JNI Interface (Java). This problem was marked solved in issue [#867](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/867), but the method implemented later changed.

According to the changelog it should be possible (in C) with `solver.smtlib2_log = file` now. However, I am unable to set this parameter in Java because it doesn't exist for `setParameter()` or any other Solver Module command. Am I missing something or is this only possible in non-JNI at the moment?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: You should really post this as a new ticket in the Z3-issues tracker, or as a comment on that ticket you referred to. This is quite an implementation specific question and as such not that appropriate for Stack-Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, smt2-logging now works and you can use it in 2 ways:

1. globally:
   set_param("solver.smtlib2_log", "log.smt2")
2. solver only:
   solver.set("smtlib2_log", "log.smt2")

with "log.smt2" beeing your logfile.